# Fix Maximum setlocal recursion level reached

Tags: batch-file

I understand this question has been asked, but this is a more specific need. I recently took upon the challenge of trying to make a simple "programming language" via nothing but batch on windows. I did. However, compiler can only process 32 setlocal's before returning the message. Because they dont close until the "end of the script" if not denoted by a endlocal, that makes 1 set local for every line in the code x number of lines
Heres what I know:
Endlocal is used to "close" setlocal essentially 
If not denoted it is automatically closed when the script exits, still preserving script - local variables. This allows setlocals purpose - script specific vars at its very core - to still work without ending it. 
This means I can execute new batch scripts in the same term instance (via just typing '%home%\software\dir.bat') without closing the original setlocal.
New scripts may then have another setlocal. This leads to the issue. It loops back into itself and that may be it.

So, heres what I dont know/the issue:

I use 1 setlocal typing the filename to compile, it opens the compiler script and that uses 1 setlocal for every line. I tried putting in an "endlocal" in the code immediately following the compilers need for the setlocal (as in once all of the commands are complete, code below), but the script just crashes. It also crashes when I try to do that in the first program as well.

Thus, I have 3 options
a: find out where to put end local's to allow the script to function / or find another solution around the message that doesn't involve using endlocals but I don't think there is one.
b: figure out a workaround for breaking up files that are more than 30 lines, but I'm 90% sure their isn't an efficient one or that theres even a point for trying at that point, I mean ---, I may as well try to program NASAS original computers to drive a Tesla. That's just too messy. Lets just ignore option B.
c: use another language for this dumb project, but again the point of this was to do it in Batch, a scripting language, so lets just problem solve limitations and stick with A.

All the setlocal enabledelayedexpansion etc is needed for in the compiler is breaking a line into arguments, then setting them to %arg1% %arg2% %arg3% etc respectively. 
Here is the relevant code in the "compiler." If somebody wants to see the full file just message me.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
<"!file!" (
  for /f %%i in ('type "!file!" ^| find /c /v ""') do set /a n=%%i && for /l %%j in (1 1 %%i) do (
    set /p "line_%%j="
REM this just breaks the file into lines
  )
)
REM this then takes the first line from that respective variable and breaks it into arguments.
set i=1
set "arg!i!=%line_1: =" & set /A i+=1 & set "arg!i!=%"
```

After this my program then checks these arguments for denoting various things (such as the end of a statement etc), then if nothing matches and the args are for a normal command, it executes the respective batch script. This uses the same arguments (%arg1% etc) set by the compiler, from breaking it into args. There wasn't a need to feed the next script args then setting them from %~1 etc as variables are kept between scripts if you open them within eachother. When these scripts are done, they denote that they are returning to a script being compiled actively, open the compiler, compiler see's this, continues to next line, where then the above code is used, and then the process repeats.

If i had to guess, because really all I'm doing is using a script to open a script that then opens the first script that opens another script that opens the first script (etc you get the point, its a big loop into itself), the setlocal gets screwed up because of the looping abuse I'm putting these scripts through.

I tried putting the endlocal at the immediate end of that code, and also right before the program executes the respective script, and at the start of the compiler, and in any location, script crashes - instantly closes. The file does not even read any commands or arguments from the file, I can see because I have a log so I see exactly where the program stopped working.

KEY QUESTION: 
Something that is interesting - in the script that executes the code to stop compiling a script as its denoted it's end, I placed an endlocal and it didnt crash. 
If setlocals are open and another script is executed in the same terminal, does it close the original setlocal, or does it carry as open unto the next script, until the entire process is given the quit command or something of that nature/closed by user? If the setlocal stays open, does that mean I could open setlocal in script1, execute script2.bat, then end script1's setlocal statement?

Be weary, I stress this - when I say execute I never mean open in another cmd window via start command, I mean open in the same running cmd window. So multiple scripts output things to the same window.

Some of these terms are likely almost overkill for this but I had lack of better terms, my apologies.

So any ideas are welcome, hopefully this makes sense but I probably could have used better terms.
I appreciate your read fellow coders!

Also, this project is 100% pointless, and completely redundant and useless in any manor - but I wanted to take up something challenging, and either way its cool to make commands and see them executed exactly as you want in order with the correct variables and arguments etc. At its core it's a pretty simple script, but because of batch limitations some methods that it uses are just a little code heavy.

Let me know what you guys think though!

Also, if I'm actually just f-ked, can I just tell cmd to just not output and output from whatever precise command causes the message to be thrown? The scripts still WORK and get compiled, the message just gets spammed between them. So, if I could just continue without caring about breaking batch, and muting the message that would be great. I tried >nul on a few commands to no avail.

Thank you.
I can always rely on stackoverflow for the ways which are above me.

Comment: This is way to broad, you do not really ask a question around a specific problem, it is more of an essay with some random, vague questions. Seems you're seeking debugging help. Also, there are no compilers here, batch files are just that, files, with batches of code, no compiling.

Comment: So don't do it. What sort of answer do you want?

Comment: To simply hide the output of exceeding setlocal maximum, Use Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 2>nul OR Setlocal 2>nul

However, I'm struggling to understand the approach you've chosen, In particular, why your Subscript would need to use Setlocal for every line. For what your Describing, Use of Arrays would seem more Suitable. I guess I'd need to See more of What your script and companion programs do and how they Function collectively to see the bigger picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some explanations to `setlocal` and `endlocal`.

Only with setlocal the mode of delayed expansion and extensions can be changed.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
setlocal EnableExtensions
```

Each setlocal pushes the current modes (extensions, delayedExpansion) and a copy of all variables to a stack.

An `endlocal` pop the modes and the variables from the stack.

BUT the `CALL` command also uses this stack, therefore it's only possible to use `endlocal` for a `setlocal` which was called in the same call level.

And an `exit`/`goto :eof` will implicitly execute all `endlocals` for the current call level.

To your problem: (I don't understand it!)

**Solution 1:** Use only ONE `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at the start of your script, that enables delayed expansion for the life time of your script.

Example with your code:

```
@echo off 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call :load_file_to_array
call :split_line_to_args 1

exit /b

:load_file_to_array
<"!file!" (
  for /f %%i in ('type "!file!" ^| find /c /v ""') do set /a n=%%i && for /l %%j in (1 1 %%i) do (
    set /p "line_%%j="
REM this just breaks the file into lines
  )
)
exit /b 

:split_line_to_args
REM this then takes the first line from that respective variable and breaks it into arguments.
set /a i=%1
set "arg!i!=%line_1: =" & set /A i+=1 & set "arg!i!=%"
exit /b
```

**Solution 2:** Use variables scopes inside of your functions with `setlocal`/`endlocal`.

That is a bit more tricky, because many functions shall modify at least one variable outside of it's scope.

Exsample with a strlen function, which only modifies the return_length variable.

```
@echo off 

set "myString=abcdefg"
call :strlen return_length myString
echo %return_length%
exit /b

:strlen <resultVar> <stringVar>
(   
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    (set^ tmp=!%~2!)
    if defined tmp (
        set "len=1"
        for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
            if "!tmp:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
                set /a "len+=%%P"
                set "tmp=!tmp:~%%P!"
            )
        )
    ) ELSE (
        set len=0
    )
)
( 
    endlocal
    set "%~1=%len%"
    exit /b
)
```

Comment: Thank you, brilliant. I don't know why I didn't think of just setting the setlocal in the first file only, so any scripts looped to after that wouldn't be opening another. Thank you mate, your explanations were really informative aswell.